# Can't add media on Orchard v.1.10.1.0

Tags: orchardcms

I did a setup of an Orchard v.1.10.1.0 with the default recipe and can't add media. The Javascript console shows this error:

```
GET https://website.azurewebsites.net/Media/Default/_Profiles/1338a03e/abbfa561/header.png?v=636100967487424883 404 (Not Found)


Uncaught TypeError: deepestChildPath.contains is not a function
```

Comment: Although using Azure blob storage does fix the issue to an extent. The deepestChildPath error still exists and the thumbnail in the admin panel is grayed out, and the "spinner" shows. But I am able to add the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in Orchard 1.10. You should be able to fix it by changing line 385 in `Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.MediaLibrary/Scripts/media-library.js`
to `var separator = deepestChildPath.indexOf('/') > -1 ? '/' : '\\';`
 as shown in [the GitHub history](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/commit/e90f114a8bb79584c0e1e08729a2101ab48b5787).